# Is there an event handler for an <a> tag that fires when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

This

```
<body onload="alert(1)"></body>
```

would alert the number 1 when the page **loads**. Is there such an event handler that this

```
<body>
  <a ???="alert(1)"></a>
</body>
```

would also alert 1 when the page is loaded?
This is an XSS question. I want to make sure that you can't execute javascript from the `<a>` tag, because I want to echo some output in it from php like this:

```
echo "<a href='" . $user_input . "' ></a>";
```

This is vulnerable to XSS but only if a person clicks, or hovers over the link. If user provides this input:

```
$user_input = "' onclick='alert(1);"
```

Then the tag would look like this:

```
<a href='' onclick='alert(1)'></a>
```

Comment: Why not appending that handler to the body?

Comment: Are you expecting that `<a>` to load at a different time than the rest of the DOM?

Comment: @Scottie Well, technically the anchor is added to the DOM before the rest of the nodes after it in the source code.

Comment: See my answer, malicious user can add value that will execute script right after element load.

Comment: You can't use that event with that tag; it only exists with tags that have to do with resources.  Can you explain why you want to know this?  Is it because you want to do something once you know that has "loaded" (is available to do something with)?  There are other ways to deal with this.

Comment: @bfavaretto Yeah, that's what I was (admittedly clumsily-worded) getting at: if the OP was expecting something different than the standard behavior.

Comment: Yes, I am expecting something that's not standard. Like a different example -  `<img src="" onerror="alert(1)" />` - this **would** alert 1 when the page loads. See what I mean now?

Answer (score 4):

Of course it is possible, if variable contains for example `'></a><script>alert(1);</script>`.
So you need to sanitize it's value anyway.

Comment: This looks like the right answer to me. Always, _always_ sanitize user input before dumping it into an HTML page. `htmlspecialchars($user_input)` should do the trick.

Comment: I used to use `htmlentities` though.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. The easiest way to make it work would be to put the function call directly after the element

```
<body>
    <a></a>
    <script>alert(1)</script>
</bodY>
```

Comment: You could add an example to your answer directly; it's a simple example, no need to make the user follow a link to see the implementation.